# SonarLint : What does SonarQube project option do?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am using SonarLint plugin for IntelliJ and when setting this up it gives me the option to select a SonarQube project from the list of all SonarQube projects available as you can see in the picture below

[image]

What exactly does this do when I select a particular project as I am not exactly clear on this and it does not explain on the [SonarLint main site](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/#Connected)?

Does it take the rules for the selected project and use these rules for any project I am working on in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option sets up "Connected Mode" so that, as you guessed, the rule set applied to your project matches the one on your server.

You explicitly connect a single workspace project to a single SonarQube project. The default rule set(s) will be used on un-connected projects.

Comment: does the rules only apply for the given project or does the rules apply for all projects in my workspace? If only the givem project, then if I have a file from another project open in my IDE what rules does SonarLint use for this?